# What does a typical developer do before publishing an app?

Tags: android, publishing

Is there a tutorial I can find somewhere that lists the ideal steps to do before publishing the app:

For example, Using bug tracer such as bugsense, encrypting the code, signing, ..etc?
I knew the above by chance when browsing stackoverflow questions and I was wondering if there is a systematic thing that developers do before publishing the app.

I couldn't find a better place to post this question, so any pointers help
Thanks

Comment: Official guide "Publishing Overview" - http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/publishing/publishing_overview.html - can be of use if not read yet.

Comment: Thank you but I was not asking about publishing or how to do so.  i am looking for best practices beford publishing  for example it does not mention anywhere how to know what crashes happened in the user device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main best practices? Create a variety of emulators, with each being a different version of Android. Do all the major things your app can do on each - take notes of any irregularities. Don't fix these one at a time, run through all of it as a 'user' rather than a developer. Even better yet, try loading your app on your friend's/peer's devices with varying Android versions and see how it runs live. Again, take note of any errors and fix them towards the end.

This is just one suggestion.

Comment: +1 for the sugggestion  thats good point that i forgot.what about crashes that happens by actual users?do u recommend bug sense?smthing else?

Comment: I am not familiar with bug sense. However, if you use Eclipse, there's a great Android Lint plugin. You can right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Run Lint. Then in the LogCat area, click on the Lint Warnings tab. It will show you common things that are not necessarily going to lead to bugs, but are not done as well as they could be. For example, using a direct string in quotes rather than referring to strings/nameValue etc. I find it quite helpful. 

You can also consider drawing out charts of how UI interactions perform, just to make sure your paradigms make sense to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Publishing Overview" in the Android Developer docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing_overview.html

Comment: Thank you but I was not asking about publishing or how to do so.  i am looking for best practices beford publishing  for example it does not mention anywhere how to know what crashes happened in the user device

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign your application. Android Tools on Eclipse provide you with tools that you can use to do this easier. You can optionally obfuscate your code if you have a reason to do so, but that is not something typically done.